# How to create table with computed column and if statement?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ddl, calculated-columns

As in title, I'm trying to create a table on SQL Server that includes computed column with if statement. I have already created basic columns, co currently trying to add computed column using ALTER TABLE.

In statement:
`ALTER table zgodnosc add proba as IIF([Zmiana_1_postoj] = 0 ,-50,[Zmiana_1]) float;`
I got error 
*Incorrect syntax near 'float'.*
I've tried lots of combinations, always getting errors. Datatypes are: Zmiana_postoj_1 - bit, Zmiana_1 - int.
Does someone have a clue how to write that correctly?
Thanks!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the `float` - SQL Server will infer the datatype from the datatype of the expression.

If you replace `-50` with `-5E1` or `-50e0` the datatype of the expression will become `float`

```
ALTER table zgodnosc add proba as IIF([Zmiana_1_postoj] = 0 ,-50e0,[Zmiana_1]);
```

though you may prefer to be more explicit about it.

Personally I prefer the conciseness of `IIF` to `CASE WHEN ELSE END`. I doubt the computed column syntax is transferable to other RDBMSs irrespective of that.

Comment: What if I want to use computed column in other computed column? I have this error: Computed column 'Doba' in table 'zgodnosc' is not allowed to be used in another computed-column definition. and I don't know if I can do anything with it

Comment: You can't nest computed columns. If you want to reuse one in another you need to copy over the definition instead, i.e. underlying `IIF` expression in this case

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, you would use:

```
alter table zgodnosc add proba as (case when Imiana_1_postoj] = 0 then -50 else Zmiana_1 end) ;
```

No type is necessary.  The additional parentheses are not necessary.  I habitually include them for two reasons.  First, they are needed for `check` constraints.  Second, they do a good job of visually delimiting the expression.

If you want a particular type, you can convert/cast:

```
alter table zgodnosc add proba as (convert(float, (case when Imiana_1_postoj] = 0 then -50 else Zmiana_1 end))
```

Note:  I strongly discourage the use of `IIF()`.  It was introduced into SQL Server for backwards compatibility to MS Access.  `CASE` is the standard method of handling conditional logic in SQL.